# Updating Cypress globally on a server

Tags: node.js, package, dependencies, cypress, dependency-management

In the team I work with, we have several test suites that are run daily through Jenkins. Currently, we are using version 12.17.0 of Cypress and would like to update to version 13.4.0.

Since there are multiple test projects, I would like to know if there is a way to update the version of all of them at once through the global installation of Cypress, without the need to update the package.json of each project.

We have already tried the global installation using the command npm install -g cypress, but it continues to use the version specified in the dependencies of the package.json.

Comment: how do you execute cypress? with npx cypress run?